# Xamarin Forms Android release build crashes when downloaded from play store but not when manually installed on the phone from PC

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, sqlite-net

I created a new release build for my Xamarin Forms Android App. I tried this both in aab format and apk the issue is the same. If I install the created release apk on my phone via USB transfer the app doesn't crash but if I upload the aab or apk to play store and download the app from there it crashes. I was able to catch the error that I receive from the play store app and is the one below.

```
SQLite.SQLiteException: no such table: Landmark
  at SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare2 (SQLitePCL.sqlite3 db, System.String query) [0x0001b] in <4b0d206650714aac95636d5649d4c03f>:0 
  at SQLite.SQLiteCommand.Prepare () [0x00011] in <4b0d206650714aac95636d5649d4c03f>:0 
  at SQLite.SQLiteCommand+<ExecuteDeferredQuery>d__12`1[T].MoveNext () [0x00060] in <4b0d206650714aac95636d5649d4c03f>:0 
  at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T].AddEnumerable (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] enumerable) [0x00059] in <9c12cec805d543baa1819a17252d0f37>:0 
  at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T]..ctor (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] collection) [0x00062] in <9c12cec805d543baa1819a17252d0f37>:0 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source) [0x00018] in <f7f5e975751f438aaf310250a4760143>:0 
  at SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteQuery[T] () [0x0001c] in <4b0d206650714aac95636d5649d4c03f>:0 
  at SQLite.TableQuery`1[T].ToList () [0x0000b] in <4b0d206650714aac95636d5649d4c03f>:0 
  at YourApp.APQ.Repositories.LandmarksRepository.get_LandmarksEurope () [0x00025] in <aac048b1ac5244308321320587a44123>:0 
  at YourApp.APQ.Services.Game.GameService.GetNextQuestionEurope () [0x00011] in <aac048b1ac5244308321320587a44123>:0
```

The issue is I assume the way play store stores this App and how it reads the SQLite Database. I tried multiple release build settings but to no success. **I must add that this error only comes up for android 13 devices when I download the app from play store I tried the play store app on an android 10 device and the app works as it should.**

This is how I use the DB

```
public List<LandmarkModel> LandmarksEurope
    {
        get
        {
            if (landmarksEurope != null) return landmarksEurope;
            landmarksEurope = new List<LandmarkModel>();
            var entities = dbConn.Table<Landmark>().ToList();
            var filtereden = entities.Where(x => x.Region == 
"EU").ToList();
            foreach (Landmark entity in entities)
            {
                if (entity.Region == "EU")
                {
                    landmarksEurope.Add(new 
LandmarkModel(entity));
                }
            }
            //entities.ForEach(e => flagsEurope.Add(new 
FlagModel(e)));
            return landmarksEurope;
        }
    }
```

This is where the exception is caught

```
var country = landmarksRepository.GetRandomFlag(c => 
playedCountries.Contains(c));
            var options = 
landmarksRepository.GetRandomFlagCountries();
            options.Add(country.Country);
            options = options.OrderBy(a => 
Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();

            var question = new Question
            {
                Flag = Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS ? 
$"landmarkspng/{country.ImageFileName}.png" : $" 
{country.ImageFileName}.png",
                Options = options,
                TheRightAnswer = country.Country
            };

            playedCountries.Add(country);

            return currentQuestion = question;
```

Comment: Is your db created on the fly, or included in the app bundle, or something else?  You haven’t shown any code or provided any detail about your db.

Comment: The database is added to the app as a separate file. The app just reads the data stored there.

Comment: Which library are you using for SQLite? The sqlite-net-pcl nuget? Did you upgrade to the latest version? Are you targeting the latest Android API?

Comment: I use sqlite-net-pcl v1.8.116 and also tried v1.7.335 and yes I am targeting android 13

Comment: @Jason I added the methods you requested

Comment: What path are you using for the connection?  My guess is that 13 can’t find the file so creates an empty db, which doesn’t have the expected tables

Comment: The DB is inside the Assets folder. string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            string dbPath = Path.Combine(path, filename);

Comment: Yes you are right about the DB the location is not recognized in android 13. But why would this happen only one the apk uploaded to the play store and not in the apk that i manually install via usb on the phone. Both apk are literally the same. Is there a different location i should be looking for the db besides string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal); in case of android 13?

Comment: That is NOT how you read assets in any version of Android.

Comment: can you please help in this case? How can i read my .sqlite3 file from the assets folder based on different android versions?

Comment: This is covered in the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/android-assets?tabs=windows

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251163/discussion-between-nysand-and-jason).

Comment: Good news I scrapped the local SQLite databases from my android and iOS projects and went for data storing on Firebase Realtime DB. All works great now and cleared much of my code that had anything to do with local SQLite db. I went for this approach because I think the issue could have also been permission based and I know in android 11 there were some major changes on that. In any case the firebase db usage instead of the local SQLite one is much better because it will be easier for me to modify the data in the future and I don’t expect usage outside of internet coverage.